# Is there a QR code reader with instant sync to PC?

Tags: applications, qr-code

QR codes are a great idea, but often I find that I would be better off reading the content on my PC instead of my phone. What I really would want is an app that would read a QR code and instantly send some kind of notification to the PC where I could access right away. I know I can use the "share" functionality of e.g. Google Goggles, but it's too many steps to achieve what I want. Basically I'd like it to happen in 3 steps:

1. Start the app
2. Point your mobile camera at the code
3. Click something on desktop UI to access it

There are too many QR code readers in the market to go through all and find if any of them has this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exact answer, but it can simplify what you want to do..

You can copy results in clipboard & get clipboard data on PC using [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) (It doesn't require internet connection; it works over internal Wi-Fi network).

Comment: Like you said, this is not the 3-click solution I have in mind, but very worthwhile suggestions at any rate, even considering other use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My app [Barcode to PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.barcodetopc) allows you to instantly send barcodes to the computer and type them.

There is also an option to automatically open the URLs in the browser, but it must be enabled in the server settings.